# Vertically aligning text next to a radio button

Tags: css, radio-button, alignment

This is a basic CSS question, I have a radio button with a small text label after it. I want the text to appear centered vertically but the text is always aligned with the button of the radio button in my case.

```
<p><input type="radio" id="opt1" name="opt1" value="1" />A label</p>
```

Here is a Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UnA6j/

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Alan.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UnA6j/5/

Comment: You should use a `<label>` for a label instead of a paragraph.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use it inside a `label`. Use `vertical-align` to set it to various values -- `bottom`, `baseline`, `middle` etc.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="oddsPref" name="oddsPref" value="decimal" /> Decimal
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" id="oddsPref" name="oddsPref" value="decimal" /> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80x30">
</label>
```

Comment: thanks... I still can't get it to align see my updated code with label.. http://jsfiddle.net/UnA6j/5/

Comment: Ok I got it working, I fiddled with your code and adjusted the radio ipnut to have a negative top margin which shifts it up so that the alignment is precise. Is negative margins accepted practise, it feels wrong! http://jsfiddle.net/UnA6j/5/

Comment: Nice.. I don't think negative margins are an issue.. if it is working across all browsers, it's good to go.. is the norm

Comment: You can also use numeric values for `vertical-align` rule. For example `vertical-align:-1px;`

Comment: Thanks, I got mine aligned with `vertical-align: sub;`

Answer (score 23):

I think this is what you might be asking for

http://jsbin.com/ixowuw/2/

```css
label {
  font-size: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <input type="radio" id="oddsPref" name="oddsPref" value="decimal" />
  <label>Decimal</label>
</span>
```

Comment: @Rahul-Thakus thanks for your code gives me the same problem.. text is aligned with the baseline....

Comment: make sure that it is not being overridden by some other parent property, btw what browser you are using?

Comment: @Protectorone have made a small change in the html and css. Please try this, should work for larger fonts too.

Comment: Also make sure your radio button doesn't have any margins on it. That screwed me up.

Answer (score 9):

Used to this

```
    input[type="radio"]{
    vertical-align:top;
    }
p{
    font-size:10px;line-height: 18px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UnA6j/8/)**

Answer (score 7):

This will give dead on alignment

```
input[type="radio"] {
  margin-top: 1px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

simple and short solution add below style:

```
style="vertical-align: text-bottom;"
```

Answer (score 5):

HTML:

```
<label><input type="radio" id="opt1" name="opt1" value="1"> A label</label>
```

CSS:

```css
label input[type="radio"] { vertical-align: text-bottom; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try something like;

```
<p><input type="radio" id="oddsPref" name="oddsPref" value="decimal" /><span>Decimal</span></p>
```

and give the span a margin top like;

```
span{
    margin-top: 4px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UnA6j/11/

Comment: I needed cross-browser placement using a relative rather than an absolute font size, which yields different sizes of text in different browsers.  Your post gave me the idea of using negative margin-top values in ems to compensate, which worked!

Answer (score 2):

You need to align the text to the left of radio button using float:left

```
input[type="radio"]{
float:left;
}
```

You may use label too for more responsive output.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try something like this:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  margin-top: -1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
  <label  class="child"><input id = "warm" type="radio" name="weathertype" value="warm" checked> Warm<br></label>
<label class="child1"><input id = "cold" type="radio" name="weathertype" value="cold" checked> Cold<br></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input.radio {vertical-align:middle; margin-top:8px; margin-bottom:12px;}
```

SIMPLY Adjust top and bottom as needed for PERFECT ALIGNMENT of radio button or checkbox

```html
<input type="radio" class="radio">
```